# Como puedo pasar los valores de una función a otra?

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

estoy tratando de crear una función para poder descargar información de una página en PDF, pero al momento de crear la función y tomar los valores de la otra, me dice que se esperaban ciertos parametros y ninguno pasó, les dejo el código, por favor!

```
public function pdf($datos, $fecha, $fecha2, $datosSegmentoEntrada1, $datosSegmentoEntrada2, $datosSegmentoEntrada3, $datosSegmentoEntrada4, $datosSegmentoEntrada5, $datosSegmentoEntrada6, $datosSegmentoEntrada7, $datosSegmentoEntrada8, $datosSegmentoEntrada9, $datosSegmentoEntrada10, $datosSegmentoEntrada11, $datosSegmentoEntrada12, $datosSegmentoEntrada13, $datosSegmentoEntrada14, $datosSegmentoEntrada15, $datosSegmentoEntrada16, $datosSegmentoSalida1, $datosSegmentoSalida2, $datosSegmentoSalida3, $datosSegmentoSalida4, $datosSegmentoSalida5, $datosSegmentoSalida6, $datosSegmentoSalida7, $datosSegmentoSalida8, $datosSegmentoSalida9, $datosSegmentoSalida10, $datosSegmentoSalida11, $datosSegmentoSalida12, $datosSegmentoSalida13, $datosSegmentoSalida14, $datosSegmentoSalida15, $datosSegmentoSalida16)
    {
        $data = self::index($datos, $fecha, $fecha2, $datosSegmentoEntrada1, $datosSegmentoEntrada2, $datosSegmentoEntrada3, $datosSegmentoEntrada4, $datosSegmentoEntrada5, $datosSegmentoEntrada6, $datosSegmentoEntrada7, $datosSegmentoEntrada8, $datosSegmentoEntrada9, $datosSegmentoEntrada10, $datosSegmentoEntrada11, $datosSegmentoEntrada12, $datosSegmentoEntrada13, $datosSegmentoEntrada14, $datosSegmentoEntrada15, $datosSegmentoEntrada16, $datosSegmentoSalida1, $datosSegmentoSalida2, $datosSegmentoSalida3, $datosSegmentoSalida4, $datosSegmentoSalida5, $datosSegmentoSalida6, $datosSegmentoSalida7, $datosSegmentoSalida8, $datosSegmentoSalida9, $datosSegmentoSalida10, $datosSegmentoSalida11, $datosSegmentoSalida12, $datosSegmentoSalida13, $datosSegmentoSalida14, $datosSegmentoSalida15, $datosSegmentoSalida16);
        
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('layouts.buscar.pdf', $data);

        return $pdf->stream();

    }
```

La función 'index' tiene todas esas variables, las cuales son las que necesito para generar el reporte el cual estoy trabajando...

Comment: El método index que retorna? una vista, un array, un json? Puedes usar dd($data); para ver que esta trayendo desde el método index, si puedes, edita la pregunta y agrega el método index también

Comment: El método index me trae la vista que tengo, ahora, dentro hay solo consultas sql

Comment: Si index te retorna una vista, allí esta el problema, si estas retornando una vista debes tener algo así al final del método index "return view('vista', compact('data'));" y deberías en el caso actual retornar un array